# Why do <Link> and <Redirect> not trigger updates of state.router in connected-react-router?

Tags: react-router, connected-react-router

After looking around at the various packages to combine redux with react-router, it  looked as though connected-react-router was the most popular actively supported choice.

I configured it pretty much exactly as in the [docs](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router), with one exception described below.

The problem I am having is that a react-router `<Redirect>` does redirect, but it does not update `state.router.location`. Codesandbox MNWE is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/connected-router-test-3weu4). [Edit: I realized just after posting that `<Link>` is having exactly the same problem, and illustrated it in a [slight modification](https://codesandbox.io/embed/connected-router-test-link-kwswl) of the original codesandbox. Sorry, would have been clearer if I'd just started there, but I need some sleep!]

In the following example, there are 3 routes. The first matches the root "/". The second matches simple URLs like "/anything" and the default will match things like "/anything/else". `<Where>` is a little component that shows its `text` prop and then shows `state.router.location.pathname`.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
        <Where text="Root" />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/:thing">
        <Where text="Exact" />
    </Route>
    <Route>
    <Redirect to="/" />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

When you arrive, you see "Root: /", as you should. If you add "/anything" in the address bar, you see "Exact: /anything". If you put "/anything/else" in the address bar, the address bar is redirected back to the root, and the `<Switch>` goes back to match the root, but instead of seeing "Root: /", you see "Root: /anything/else". The logger confirms that although the manually entered URLs trigger `state` updates, the `<Redirect>` does not.

Maybe I am wrong to think that it should, but I don't see it documented one way or the other. I imagine that I have made some configuration  error?

[The configuration exception that I described is that I do not use `combineReducers` in my App, I have a single reducer which I call `appRootReducer` (which is empty in this  example). So I wrote a little `createRootReducer` wrapper.  It works well enough that the basic updates to `state.router` do go through.]

I hope that you can help!

Comment: Here are the versions in the codesandbox demo: react & react-dom@16.8.6; connected-react-router@6.4.0; react-router-dom@5.0.1; redux@4.0.1. I had originally installed react-redux v7 but in fact this demo doesn't depend on it. I uninstalled it and had the same problem. In the second demo, which uses <Link>, the problem persisted after downgrading to react-redux@6.0.1

Comment: In the second example, using both `<Link>` and `<Redirect>`, I eliminated the reducer changes I was using, and copied the standard configuration essentially exactly. I also added explanatory text so that it's clearer what the expected behavior should be. https://codesandbox.io/embed/connected-router-test-link-kwswl

Comment: I put the second example, with more explanation, [in the "Issues" on the [connected-react-router GitHub page](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/324).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ack! Searching through closed issues in the Github repo, I see that I had left in my `<BrowswerRouter>` tags.

> - Wrap your react-router v4/v5 routing with `ConnectedRouter` and pass the `history` object as a prop.  Remember to delete any usage of
>     `BrowserRouter` or `NativeRouter` as leaving this in will
>     [cause](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/230#issuecomment-461628073)
>     [problems](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/230#issuecomment-476164384)
>     synchronising the state.